# CentOS 7 - upgrade PHP version from 7.2 to 8

Tags: nginx, centos, php, php-fpm

- CentOS 7
- Nginx
- Current websites run on PHP 7.2

`PHP -v` says

````
```# php -v
PHP 8.0.25 (cli) (built: Oct 25 2022 09:42:31) ( NTS gcc x86_64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group```
````

But phpinfo() in the nginx server shows:
`PHP Version 7.2.34`

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc/opt/remi/php72
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/opt/remi/php72/php.ini
```

Nginx site config:

```
location ~ \.php$ {

               fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9072;   #set port for php-fpm to listen on
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include         fastcgi_params;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;


        }
```

How I can upgrade my PHP to 8? (Or, why it's not updating/changing in the website level)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> /etc/opt/remi/php72

Looks like you have installed multiple version of PHP.

> fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9072;

This is the listen socket defined in the FPM configuration file for PHP 7.2 (in /etc/opt/remi/php72/php-fpm.d)

Simply change this to the one defined in the FPM configuration file for PHP 8.0 (see /etc/php-fpm.d)

You have to start (if not yet used) the FPM 8.0 service (probably "php-fpm")

You can also stop (if not used anymore) the FPM 7.2 service (probably "php72-php-fpm").

If you don't need PHP 7.2 anymore you can also uninstall it

```
dnf remove 'php72*'
```

Reminders:

- for a proper repository configuration, follow the [wizard instruction](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/)
- CentOS 7 is old and close to its end of life (June 2024), I recommend a modern version (EL-8 or EL-9) especially to run modern software such as PHP 8.